# How to store historical master data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

Let's assume a simple scenario in which we have 3 tables `Employee`, `Designation` & `Allowance`:

[image: Employee Table]

[image]

[image]

The problem that I face is that employee's designation & allowance amounts associated with designation may change in the future.

If any such change occurs, the new allowances will be given as per new master data. But reports of old months will now show invalid data. Because John is an officer right now & getting allowances according to his designation. But in future he might get a promotion and his designation may change to manager. Then he will get allowances for manager. Then, if some one go to allowance report and filter john's data for a previous month. The report will show allowances given to john as an officer but his designation in that report will be manager because designation id of john has been updated.

So my question is that, What is the best way to record, maintain & track master data in such a way that the transactional data associated with it remains valid even if the master data gets changed in future.

Comment: It's called Slowly Changing Dimensions

Comment: Any idea, how to deal with them in a relational database?

Comment: Do I have to maintain versions of such dimension every time they change, and then associate my transactional data with this version instead of the orignal dimension's table. OR Should I store all such data in a denormalized fashion with in the the transaction itself so that in my reports I dont have to query any other table and all master data that was applicable at the time of transaction is stored in that transaction itself.

Comment: There are different methods to this. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) for example, there are also many ideas all over the web

Comment: Aside, you're already denormalizing the `Amount`, it seems, so you already have a historical record of how much of an allowance was applied per employee based on their contemporary designation.

Comment: Yes, I do have the amount that was given to employees. But the problem is that I dont have a history of designations, that what was the designation of these employees when this amount was given to them. And designation is only an example that I have used here to explain my problem. The project that I am working on have many such dimensions like city, supervisor, team, grade etc. All these dimensions are used in different business rules. And these rules generate different transactional data. And I am unable to track the state of such dimensions at the time transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Temporal Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) to automatically capture historical versions of rows and enable you to query "as-of" previous points in time.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need an another table, like `CurrentAmount` to record Allowance per date that represent you, which Employee, with what designation, in each day have got how much allowance.